# How to calculate the log of a number using bc?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, bc

I want to calculate the log (base 10) of a number. How can I do this using `bc`?

Comment: They should've just called it 'log' or 'ln'. Who expects 'l'?

Comment: @polynomial_donut all the basic functions included in the math library (`bc -l`) have single-character names. The cosine function is `c`. It's a feature ;)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Invoke `bc` with the `-l` option (to enable the math library) like so:

```
$ echo 'l(100)/l(10)' | bc -l
2.00000000000000000000
```

Use the `l` function which is the natural log.  Take the natural log of the number you are interested in then divide it by the natural log of 10.

Comment: log_b(x) = log_k(x) / log_k(b) :-)  the logarithm in respect to base b can be computed given any logarithm function to a arbitrary base k

Comment: Not to be picky but you should really use `bc -l <<<l(100)/l(10)`, at least you don't worry about quoting.

Comment: no, the single-quoted variant is correct (`echo '...'`); with "here strings" (`<<<`) do you need to worry about quoting ("here strings...undergo brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.") https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings

Comment: In order to `scale` use `scale=2;echo 'l(100)/l(10)' | bc -l` or even better combine it with @yegle's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962283/how-do-i-calculate-the-log-of-a-number-using-bc#comment53331254_7962297)

Answer (score 53):

the logarithm of x in respect to base b can be computed given any logarithm function to an arbitrary base k -- that's actually pretty cool!

```
log_b(x) = log_k(x) / log_k(b)
```

e.g.

```
log_b(x) = ln(x) / ln(b)
```

if b=10:

```
log_10(x) = ln(x) / ln(10)
```

and -l in bc enables the math library

so that's why this works:

```
# bc -l
l(100) / l(10)
2.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: Yeah I wasn't very clear on that... I just didn't know the name of the function in `bc`. I know how to calculate it for different bases :)

Answer (score 6):

If you start `bc` with the `-l` switch, then there's a function `l()` that calculates the natural log of its argument.

Answer (score 2):

bc does not directly gives the logarithm in other than except or in other ways, using bc, we can calculate only ln(x). So, to get any other base logarithm, it is wise to remember some identities. The basic one is -

```
log base 10 (x) = log base e (x) / log base e (10)
```

Here I am giving you some examples of different base logarithms -

```
totan@Home-Computer ~ $ bc -l
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 

l(8)/l(2)
3.00000000000000000002

l(1000)/l(10)
3.00000000000000000000

l(100000)/l(100)
2.50000000000000000000

l(100000)/l(10)
5.00000000000000000001

l(81)/l(3)
4.00000000000000000001

l(64)/l(4)
3.00000000000000000000

quit()
totan@Home-Computer ~ $
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: nicely copied from my answer..

Answer (score 1):

```
bc -l

l(____)
```

(fill in the blank there with your number)

I found tutorials at:

http://unix-simple.blogspot.com/2006/10/unix-basic-calculator.html

and

http://unix-simple.blogspot.com/2006/10/taking-roots-with-unix-basic.html

Comment: log() option does not work. I get a 'function log not defined error'

Comment: yep.  I mistyped "log" for "l" in my excited hurry to get an answer in before the stampede.

Comment: This is log base e, OP specifically asked for base 10.

Answer (score 1):

Poster specifically requested log 10.

I have bc 1.06.95 on Ubuntu 12.10. "l(x)" in this version of BC is not 
base 10. It is natural log (base e). This is confirmed here and BC has 
worked this way since some time:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_bc.htm

I suspect what you need to make log base 10 work is the BC extension:

http://x-bc.sourceforge.net/extensions_bc.html

Not sure correct way to install this, and got errors trying to post it here.

Dominic-Luc Webb

Comment: The previous answers were pretty clear about it being natural log, which is the normal default on calculators, etc.  If you look at that extensions file the `log()` function just does exactly what was suggested here, `return(l(x)/l(10))`.

Answer (score 1):

As many others have pointed out, `bc` invoked with the `-l` option will include the standard math libraries, and offer their functionality through extensions. @dee pointed to additional extensions that solved the problem I had of calculating `log2()` that led me to this post. I've found no way to "install" them, but they can be loaded at runtime by including the file when invoking `bc`:

```
bc -l extensions.bc
```

If you want to make this the default behavior, define the environment variable `BC_ENV_ARGS` to `-l /pathToExtension/extensions.bc` in your shell's profile or .rc

Answer (score 0):

Since `bc -l` only gives you the natural logarithm you can define the log function quickly yourself:

```
define log(x) { return l(x)/l(10) }
log(10)
1.0000000
```