# Compute logarithms in dc

Tags: unix, logarithm, dc

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7962283/2093695) for bc, but how do you do this in dc? For example, if the command were `q`, I would want to use it like this:

```
10k
5q2q/
```

To compute `log_2(5)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in command for this in `dc`, but you can implement any of the [numerical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Numerical_value) for computing a logarithm as macros.

For example, [this one](https://gist.github.com/eush77/eb8862848ac6713e44a521ad37566501) computes `ln(x)` using `ln((1+y)/(1-y))` Taylor series expansion:

```
# L (x -- y)
# Natural logarithm of `x`.
[ 1-d2+/
  d2*Sk              # Initialize multiplier
  d*Sy               # Initialize multiplier factor
  0Ss                # Initialize accumulator
  10K^Sp             # Initialize 10^k power
  [ d1r/lk*ls+lsrdss   # Update accumulator
    -lp*d*1 [s_q]s_>_  # Check precision
    lkly*sk 2+         # Update multiplier and counter
    lfx
  ]Sf
  1lfxLs
LkLyLpLfs_s_s_s_] sL
```

Use it like this:

```
10k
5lLx 2lLx /p
```

It's not optimal, in particular for large numbers (x ≫ 1), but a method with a faster convergence can also be implemented this way, if needed.

Squeezed version (somewhat faster):

```
[1-d2+/d2*Skd*Sy0Ss10K^Sp[d1r/lk*ls+lsrdss-lp*d*1[s_q]s_>_lkly*sk2+lfx]Sf1lfxLsLkLyLpLfs_s_s_s_]sL
```