# How to find values 2 exponential in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to find a value's 2 exponential form in bash.

For example if I input 512 it should result output as 9 meaning 2 ^ 9 is 512.

Any help here is immensely appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Can the input be any value, or do you already know for sure that it's a power of 2?

Comment: In other words: How to calculate the base 2 logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`.

```
$ echo 512 | awk '{print log($1)/log(2)}'
9
```

Put that into a script (`expo.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

_num="$1"
expon=$(awk -v a="$_num" 'BEGIN{print log(a)/log(2)}')
if [[ $expon =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]*$ ]]; then # Match floating points
    echo "$_num is not an exponent of 2"; # Not exponent if floating point
else 
    echo "$_num = 2^${expon}"; # print number
fi
```

Run:

```
$ ./expo.sh 512
512 = 2^9
$ ./expo.sh 21
21 is not an exponent of 2
```

Comment: or `awk -v a=512 'BEGIN{print log(a)/log(2)}'`

Answer (score 4):

When I read the question, 512 is the input, and 9 is the output.  Is is possible what is being asked here is the answer to "log_base_2(512)" which has an answer of "9". If so, then maybe this would help.

```
$ echo "l(512) / l(2)" | bc -l
9.00000000000000000008
```

The explanation of the math can be found here:

[How do I calculate the log of a number using bc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962283/how-do-i-calculate-the-log-of-a-number-using-bc)

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to check a number `x` is an 2 exponent is to check bitwise and `x` and `x-1` and to exclude 0, `x>0`

```
((x>0 && ( x & x-1 ) == 0 )) && echo $x is a 2-exponent
```

using this [algorithm: fast-computing-of-log2-for-64-bit-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376288/fast-computing-of-log2-for-64-bit-integers) to compute log2

```
tab32=( 0  9  1 10 13 21  2 29
       11 14 16 18 22 25  3 30
        8 12 20 28 15 17 24  7
       19 27 23  6 26  5  4 31 )


log2_32() {
    local value=$1
    (( value |= value >> 1 ))
    (( value |= value >> 2 ))
    (( value |= value >> 4 ))
    (( value |= value >> 8 ))
    (( value |= value >> 16 ))
    log2_32=${tab32[(value * 16#7C4ACDD & 16#ffffffff)>>27]}
}

log2_32 262144 
echo "$log2_32"
```

Comment: Thank you @stephen

Comment: Thank you @iamuser, it helped :-)